# How to disable compose key on fedora 28?

Tags: fedora, compose-key

I'm on Fedora 28 gnome desktop interface. Some time ago I *mistakenly* set the right Ctrl key as compose key.

Because of this, after every reboot, the right Ctrl key (`rctrl`) is inactive --  for e.g. rctrl+A won't take the cursor to the beginning of the prompt line when working in CLI or rctrl+W won't close an unnecessary tab in MozFirefox. `setxkbmap -query` produces

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     it,it
variant:    ,
options:    compose:rctrl
```

Every time I must manually give `setxkbmap -option` to unset it or disable it, but after reboot it again reverts to `compose:rctrl`.

Is there a file I can edit to make the change permanent?

---

### Content of file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf

```
# Written by systemd-localed(8), read by systemd-localed and Xorg. It's
# probably wise not to edit this file manually. Use localectl(1) to
# instruct systemd-localed to update it.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "it"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection
```

---

### Content of file /etc/vconsole.conf

```
KEYMAP=it
FONT=eurlatgr
```

Comment: I'm not a Fedora user, but why couldn't you just use the exact same process you used to “ *mistakenly* set it to the right Ctrl key”, to remove it or set it to another place ? (I personally set it to the 3rd level (Alt-gr+Shift) of both windows keys and its quite useful there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the "GNOME Tweaks" application. (Hit the overview key, type `tweaks`, and it should come up either as already installed or available to install in Software.)

In that application, find the **Keyboard & Mouse** tab. This is on F29 beta so it might be slightly different, but the concept is the same:

[image: tweaks]

Click where I've circled — it'll bring up this dialog:

[image: compose key dialog]

Where you can either turn the key off or select a different one. (Personally, I find this a lovely use for Caps Lock, although you can see I set it to Right Alt on my current system.)

Comment: This worked! Thanks mate! I wonder what is the CLI equivalent of GNOME-Tweaks. Is it `gsettings ` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The command you'll need is `localectl`.

I don't have Fedora 28 at hand for testing right now, but as the command syntax is:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap <layout> [model [variant [options]]]
```

I believe the command should be something like:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap it pc105
```

Leaving the variant and options slots empty will remove existing variant/options settings.

The settings might be stored in `/etc/vconsole.conf` for the console, and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` for the X11 GUI. No clue about Wayland, but the `localectl` command is supposed to handle it all for you.

Comment: I tried that -- after reboot, I again find the option `compose:rctrl`. See content of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` file posted in the OP.

Comment: OK, then it might be your desktop environment maintaining its own set of keymap settings. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317057/258991) indicates you can wipe out GNOME's keymap tracking with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources '[]'`.